# Validate input check ONLY when display=none (div is shown)

Tags: javascript, forms

when pressing the radio button "option" it displays a div using the (display:none display:block) method. The input "Requirements" is required and has that in the html. The problem is that when pressing submit, the form requires that input even if the div isn't being shown bc the user hasn't selected the radio button which blocks the css. The field should only be required if the user has selected the radio button option.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/[jquery version here]/jquery.min.js"
language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Test</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding: 80px;
        }
        #requirements {
        width: 100%;
        }
        #results {
        width: 100%;
        }


    </style>

<script type="text/javascript">



// DISPLAY HIDDEN TEXT
function hide() {
  document.getElementById('hidden').style.display ='none';
}
function show() {
  document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'block';
}

function hidetext() {
    document.getElementById('hiddentwo').style.display = 'none';
}

function showtext() {
    document.getElementById('hiddentwo').style.display = 'block';
}

function validateForm(e) {
    let inp=[...document.getElementsByName("tick")];
    if(!inp.some(i=>i.checked) && chk.checked) {
        e.preventDefault();
      alert('You must select why you are attending!');
    }

}





</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Registration Request</h1>

<form id="form" method="post" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#">

        <p>This course is identified in my Work Plan and Learning Agreement</p>
        <input type="radio" name="optionOne" value="yes" onclick="hide()" required> Yes<br>
        <input type="radio" id="chk" name="optionOne" value="no" onclick="show()"> No<br>
        <div id="optionOne_error" class="val_error"></div>

    <p>
        <div id="hidden" style="display: none">
        <p>I am attending this session because (tick all that apply) </p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tick" value="It will help me develop the skills and knowledge required for my current role" > It will help me develop the skills and knowledge required for my current role<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tickone" value="It will help me develop the skills and knowledge for a possible future role/body of work" > It will help me develop the skills and knowledge for a possible future role/body of work <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ticktwo" value="t was identified as a need during my performance management discussions"> It was identified as a need during my performance management discussions<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tickthree" value="My manager recommended that I attend"> My manager recommended that I attend<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tickfour" value="I am interested in the content"> I am interested in the content<br>
        <p>

        <p>What would you like to achieve as a result of your attendance? For example, "I would like to learn to write better emails to improve my communication skills." </p>
        <input type="text" id="results" name="results">
</div>


<p>Do you require adjustments or additions to the session delivery to support your participation? For example, hearing loop or wheelchair access.</p>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="yes" onclick="showtext()" required> Yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="no" onclick="hidetext()"> No<br>

        <div id="option_error" class="val_error"></div>

<div id="hiddentwo" style="display: none;">
    <p>Please provide details of your requirments.</p>
<input type="text" id="requirements" name="requirements" ></input>
</div>



<p>Please upload any supporting documentation to support your registration request </p>
<div class="browse-button">
  <input type="file" name="attachments[]" multiple="multiple"></input>
</div>

<div class="submit-button">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="validateForm(event)" value="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

</form>

<img src="Logo.png" alt="Persuit Technology Logo" width="110" style="margin-top: 20px">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just give your "yes" option a specific id and then check if that id is checked.

Comment: In your `show` and `hide` functions add or remove the `required` attribute right before/after you show or hide.

Comment: Could you give an example? Im new to this

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that not you also disable the `input` tag inside the`div` when hiding it.

So the `hide` function would be:

```
function hide() {
   var inputs = document.getElementById('hidden').getElementsByTagName('input');

   for(i = 0; i < inputs.length ; i++)
       inputs[i].disabled = true

   document.getElementById('hidden').style.display ='none';

}
```

And the `show` function would be:

```
function show() {
   var inputs = document.getElementById('hidden').getElementsByTagName('input');

   for(i = 0; i < inputs.length ; i++)
       inputs[i].disabled = false

   document.getElementById('hidden').style.display ='block';

}
```

You can use also use those functions for `showText` and `hideText`.